# How to configure sonarcloud analysis for Javascript project using Azure DevOps

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am looking for steps to configure sonarcloud analysis for one of our javascript projects, with Azure DevOps as the build platform.

The following links have given us some information to start.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to below steps:

1, Create sonarcloud server, and create a SonarQube Project and configure Quality Gate on the server. you can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/) of creating sonarcloud server on azure.

2, And set up [sonarqube service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) on your azure devops project.

**Project settings**-->**Service connections** (under **Pipelines**)--> **New service connection**--> Choose Sonarqube. Please refer [here to Get a sonarqube security token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/)

3, Go to azure devops marketplace to install [Sonarqube extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) to your azure devops organization.

4, [Create a build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2) to build your project. Please check the document to [Build, test, and deploy JavaScript and Node.js apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops).

5, Create a sonar-project.properties file with below contents in the root of your project. Click [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) for more information

```
sonar.projectKey=projectKey
sonar.projectName=projectName
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=mainsourcefilesfolder #eg. dist
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.tests=testcodesourcefolder
```

5, Add below three sonarqube tasks to the end of your pipeline(after build task). For below example in yaml pipeline.

Note: SonarQube is only working on the master branch. Please run your pipeline against master branch. Check [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/community-edition-with-vsts-to-use-the-property-sonar-branch-name-the-branch-plugin-is-required-but-not-installed/1686/5) for more information.

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run build'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run build'

- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: sonarqubeConnectionName
    scannerMode: CLI
    configFile: sonar-project.properties

- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4

- task: SonarQubePublish@4
```

Then you should be able to see the analysis result on the sonar server after you finish running your build pipeline.

Hope above helps!

Comment: Could you share information about setting up analysis for feature branches for Sonar cloud private repository. Secondly, how can we configure the build breaker task?

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the above answer from @Levi Lu-MSFT. In the 3rd step, you can additionally install the [SonarQube Build Breaker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimondeLang.sonar-buildbreaker).

Then you can add an additional step in YAML after SonarQube Analyze to run the build breaker test so that the Pipeline will break when the SonarQube Analysis fails. Otherwise, even though the Analysis Fails the Pipeline will be a success.

You can use the *Assitant* to add the Breaker task or setup as below with the correct ***SonarConnectionName***

```
- task: sonar-buildbreaker@8
  inputs:
    SonarQube: sonarqubeConnectionName
```